# Adding Dynamic Routes in Web Gardens

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms, routes, web-garden

I am adding a route dynamically to the RouteTable, but the update is not propagating to the other processes:

```
using (RouteTable.Routes.GetWriteLock())
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(
        String.Format("_{0}", routeName), 
        routeName, 
        "~/Template.aspx", 
        true, 
        new RouteValueDictionary {{"page", routeName}});
}
```

This correctly creates the correct route, as I can access it sometimes, but if get switched to a new process or if I try a bit later on, I can't access the page.
If I then restart the app pool, it works fine. Also if I wait long enough, a few hours, when the processes have been recycled, the routes work.

I am thinking that this is a result of a route being created on the one process, and only on future process recycles.

Hay ideas on how to push the route updates out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the implementation of `Routes`. As we can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.routes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - `RouteTable.Routes` is static. So the issue here is not why the routes are not propogating to all processes, but more of a static variable in a web garden issue.

Trying to think of a workaround, what I can come up with is a solution similar to the sharing cache between web garden processes / web servers in a cluster. You need to take the list of dynamic routes `OutProc` and in to a DB or static file. Your code then needs to track these files for changes and add new routes when they are added to the external resource.